# Problems with custom PyPi server

Tags: python, pypi

I am trying to solve a problem with a custom PyPi server. The server is online and reachable and by configuring `~/.pip/pip.conf` to

```
[global]
trusted-host=my-server
index-url=https://my-server/simple/
```

I was able to install packages from the server. Furthermore, if a package was not available on the server, pip automatically fell back to https://pypi.python.org/pypi. This was definitely the case and colleagues of mine confirme this. However, yesterday I realised that this is apparently not the case any more. If a package is not available on the server, pip will now not fall back to the official PyPi server any more and the installation will fail. However, by modifying `~/.pip/pip.conf` to

```
[global]
trusted-host=my-server
extra-index-url=https://my-server/simple/
```

the problem can be solved. Nevertheless, I am still wondering what happened and I hope that someone can help my to investigate. Things that I believe are useful to know:

- The server was setup using http://djangopypi2.readthedocs.io
- I have full root access to the server so I am able to check/do whatever is necessary
- There is a sqlite3 database in the `djangopypi2` root directory. If I take a look at it using `cat`, I can see things like

  Ag2016-10-29 21:02:11.759771Redirect to http://pypi.python.org/simple/sixM??i

  which seem to indicate that redirection once worked (as I wrote).

I have really no clue where to start, any help would be appreciated.